# HTML Code for Calculating Marks

Tags: html

So, I created HTML code for calculating marks but It does not run.

```
<head> 
  <title>try to count</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  <!-- 
   var totalMarkCounted=0; 
   function calculate(){ 
    var subject1 = window.prompt ("Enter mark for subject 1:"); 
    var subject2 = window.prompt ("Enter mark for subject 2:"); 
    var total2subject = subject1 + subject2; 
    totalMarkCounted = totalMarkCounted+ total2subject; 
    document.write("<br>Total 2 Subject: ",total2subject); 
    document.write("<br>Total Mark Counted : ",totalMarkCounted ); 
   } 
 } 
// --> 
</script> 
</head> 

<body onload="calculate()"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first i think you have an extra "}" and you need to add the following to the very top of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

second, remove the space between the "window.prompt" and the "("

```
var subject1 = window.prompt("Enter mark for subject 1:");
```

here is the full corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>try to count</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
var totalMarkCounted=0; 
function calculate(){
var subject1 = window.prompt("Enter mark for subject 1:"); 
var subject2 = window.prompt("Enter mark for subject 2:"); 

var total2subject = parseFloat(subject1) + parseFloat(subject2); 
totalMarkCounted = totalMarkCounted+ total2subject; 
document.write("<br>Total 2 Subject: ",total2subject); 
document.write("<br>Total Mark Counted : ",totalMarkCounted ); 
} 
// --> 
</script> 
</head> 

<body onload="calculate()"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: note, if the user enters anything other than a number, the function returns NaN, you may want to check the inputs and catch that error if it is important to you.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<html>
<head>
<title>try to count</title> 
<script>  
<!--
    var totalMarkCounted=0; 
    function calculate(){ 
    var subject1 = window.prompt ("Enter mark for subject 1:"); 
    var subject2 = window.prompt ("Enter mark for subject 2:"); 

    var total2subject = parseFloat(subject1) + parseFloat(subject2); 
    totalMarkCounted = totalMarkCounted+ total2subject; 
    document.write("<br>Total 2 Subject: ",total2subject); 
    document.write("<br>Total Mark Counted : ",totalMarkCounted ); 
    } 
-->
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="calculate()"> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Basically

1. Extra `}`
2. no `<html>` opening tag
3. Not converting input strings to float, so basically it was doing string concatenation